Як краще замінити "до кінця початку" / "старого початку" 19 століття?
Я перекладаю таку ділянку тексту (для дубляжу):

"Schopenhauer belongs chronologically and biographically to the old
early 19th century."

і перекладач пропонує

"Шопенгауер хронологічно та біографічно належить до старого
початку 19 століття."

але мені не подобається цей варіант. Можна "до кінця початку", але найбільш притомним здається поки що "кінця першої половини".
Справа в тому що лектор хоче підкреслити що Шопенгауер належить до періоду 1819-1848. Тому не можна сказати "до середини" або "у першій половині".

«Друга чверть N століття» може бути гарним кандидатом:
Наприклад, Бібліотечний портал Національної академії наук України

Омельчук О. Р.
Український націоналізм другої чверті XX століття: сучасний погляд


Дякую! Так дуже релевантно

«Пізній початок 19 століття». Ось приклади вжитку:

Пізній новий період — у багатьох періодизаціях історії людства це період, який іде наступним за раннім новим періодом.


Людмила Гоц (2019). Історія культури нового та новітніх часів. НАКККІМ. с 11.
